Old film in which the protagonists use a derelict tank to fight off hostile Arab warriors
I saw this film when I was quite young, my recollection is quite hazy but these are the details I can recall:

It was probably made in the 50's or 60's, possibly in black and white.
A group of men were lost in the desert, they might have been employees of an oil company whose plane has crashed.
They discover a derelict World War II tank, I think they may have tried to use its radio to call for help.
They are attacked by hostile tribesmen, they use the tanks machine gun to fight off the attack and I think they are running low on ammunition.
I'm reasonably sure the tank is immobilised. 

That's all I can recall and these details are hazy at best, the bit that sticks in my mind is them fighting off the attack with the machine gun. Does anyone knows the title or any info on this film?

Sounds like The Steel Lady from 1953.

Surviving a plane crash in the Sahara, four oilmen find and manage to repair a German Afrika Corps tank which had been buried in the sand since WWII. Heading toward a French Foreign Legion outpost, they encounter a nomadic Arab tribe who believe the oilmen have found the treasure of Calipha, a rival Arab leader. If trying to acquire the jewels by guile doesn't work, the Arabs are prepared to kill the oilmen to get the stolen treasure.

Here's a scene like the one you described (where they use the tank to fend off the Arab tribe):




That's definitely the movie, though I don't remember the tank being mobile I thought it was old and rusted, but imperfect memory aside it is the movie I saw.
